# Inotify event in C

Tags: c, inotify

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = inotify_init();
    int wd1 = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/guest/a", IN_MODIFY);
    struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event*) malloc(sizeof(struct inotify_event));
    read(fd, event, 1000);
    if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
        printf("File '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
File '' is modified
$
```

I expected that the above program will notify with the filename if file a is modified. But it notify without filename. So,
how to get the filename if the file is modified using inotify.

Comment: [Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`, and `void *` in c in general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And you really don't need to `malloc()` anything at all. Just `struct inotify_event event; read(fd, &event, sizeof(event))`. will do

Comment: Check the return value of `read()`.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says:

> The name field is present only when an event is returned for a file
>          inside a watched directory; it identifies the file pathname relative
>          to the watched directory.  This pathname is null-terminated, and may
>          include further null bytes ('\0') to align subsequent reads to a
>          suitable address boundary.

So your problem is that you're expecting inotify to "echo" the name back to you, but that is not how it works.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes,  you can keep your own mapping of watch descriptors to filenames.  This has been discussed a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9313324/4323

Comment: It is the only way to get the filename. But this scenario will also fail in some condition like if more than one file is added to fd passed to notify_add_watch function.

Comment: @mrg: No.  Every time you add a watch,  you get a new watch descriptor.  There is therefore a mapping from watch descriptors to watches, and one watch on one file has a filename.

Comment: @iharob: There is no "watched directory" in the OP's case: the code watches `/home/guest/a` and the OP says that `a` is a file.  No directory is watched.  Therefore no names are reported.  Because they are meant to be inferred from the watch descriptor.

Comment: That clears things up. It doesn't make sense to return the name of the watched "*file*" because you know the name or else, how did you start watchng it in the first place? I Appologize, let me remove the comments.